# JellyBean Layout Crash

Tags: android, android-layout, android-webview, android-4.2-jelly-bean

I have an app with a `RelativeLayout` that contains a `ProgressBar` and a `WebView`.  There's nothing complex to it.  However, I am getting a very strange crash where I am not even seeing the ANR dialog.  Commenting out the `ProgressBar` in the xml allows the app to not crash, however I'd like to use it.  Any ideas why its crashing?

The xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/mainLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progress"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="2dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
        android:indeterminate="false"
        android:indeterminateOnly="false"
        android:maxHeight="2dp"
        android:minHeight="2dp"
        android:progressDrawable="@android:drawable/progress_horizontal" />

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:scrollbars="none" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

The log output:

```
09-06 16:57:41.233: I/ActivityManager(358): Displayed com.example.myapp.video/.MainActivity: +341ms
09-06 16:57:41.313: D/dalvikvm(27248): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 3498K, 42% free 19676K/33543K, paused 47ms, total 50ms
09-06 16:57:41.423: D/dalvikvm(27248): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1565K, 41% free 19940K/33543K, paused 54ms, total 54ms
09-06 16:57:41.583: E/SQLiteLog(14294): (14) cannot open file at line 30174 of [00bb9c9ce4]
09-06 16:57:41.583: E/SQLiteLog(14294): (14) os_unix.c:30174: (2) open(/CachedGeoposition.db) - 
09-06 16:57:41.583: D/WebKit(14294): ERROR: 
09-06 16:57:41.583: D/WebKit(14294): SQLite database failed to load from /CachedGeoposition.db
09-06 16:57:41.583: D/WebKit(14294): Cause - unable to open database file
09-06 16:57:41.583: D/WebKit(14294): external/webkit/Source/WebCore/platform/sql/SQLiteDatabase.cpp(71) : bool WebCore::SQLiteDatabase::open(const WTF::String&, bool)
09-06 16:57:41.673: D/TilesManager(14294): new EGLContext from framework: 66233588 
09-06 16:57:41.673: D/GLWebViewState(14294): Reinit shader
09-06 16:57:41.673: D/GLWebViewState(14294): Reinit transferQueue
09-06 16:57:44.913: A/libc(14294): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00000008 (code=1), thread 14294 (ample.myapp.video)
09-06 16:57:45.013: I/DEBUG(122): *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
09-06 16:57:45.013: I/DEBUG(122): Build fingerprint: 'google/nakasi/grouper:4.1.1/JRO03D/402395:user/release-keys'
09-06 16:57:45.013: I/DEBUG(122): pid: 14294, tid: 14294, name: ample.myapp.video  >>> com.example.myapp.video <<<
09-06 16:57:45.013: I/DEBUG(122): signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 00000008
09-06 16:57:45.083: I/DEBUG(122):     r0 662b1f78  r1 00002060  r2 00000000  r3 00000004
09-06 16:57:45.083: I/DEBUG(122):     r4 00000008  r5 66323060  r6 00000008  r7 00000010
09-06 16:57:45.083: I/DEBUG(122):     r8 00000008  r9 00002060  sl 6630cee4  fp 00000004
09-06 16:57:45.083: I/DEBUG(122):     ip 00000000  sp bee12308  lr 67643fa0  pc 67643d14  cpsr 20000010
09-06 16:57:45.083: I/DEBUG(122):     d0  0000000b44921000  d1  4138000041300000
09-06 16:57:45.083: I/DEBUG(122):     d2  4445400044920000  d3  000004904491a000
09-06 16:57:45.083: I/DEBUG(122):     d4  0000048d00000315  d5  444540000000048d
09-06 16:57:45.083: I/DEBUG(122):     d6  4492000000000315  d7  3f800000000004b5
09-06 16:57:45.083: I/DEBUG(122):     d8  c0000000c0000000  d9  0000000000000000
09-06 16:57:45.083: I/DEBUG(122):     d10 0000000000000000  d11 0000000000000000
09-06 16:57:45.083: I/DEBUG(122):     d12 0000000000000000  d13 0000000000000000
09-06 16:57:45.083: I/DEBUG(122):     d14 0000000000000000  d15 0000000000000000
09-06 16:57:45.083: I/DEBUG(122):     d16 4092400000000000  d17 7e37e43c8800759c
09-06 16:57:45.083: I/DEBUG(122):     d18 0000000000000000  d19 0000000000000000
09-06 16:57:45.083: I/DEBUG(122):     d20 0000000000000000  d21 0000000000000000
09-06 16:57:45.083: I/DEBUG(122):     d22 0000000000000000  d23 0000000000000000
09-06 16:57:45.083: I/DEBUG(122):     d24 3ff26a7f0aacdd31  d25 3ff550a851800000
09-06 16:57:45.083: I/DEBUG(122):     d26 0000000000000000  d27 0000000000000000
09-06 16:57:45.083: I/DEBUG(122):     d28 4091fc0002180000  d29 0000000000000000
09-06 16:57:45.083: I/DEBUG(122):     d30 bff550a861e00000  d31 0000000000000000
09-06 16:57:45.083: I/DEBUG(122):     scr 20000012
09-06 16:57:45.093: I/DEBUG(122): backtrace:
09-06 16:57:45.093: I/DEBUG(122):     #00  pc 0003bd14  /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_tegra.so
09-06 16:57:45.093: I/DEBUG(122):     #01  pc 0003bf9c  /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_tegra.so
09-06 16:57:45.093: I/DEBUG(122):     #02  pc 0003c470  /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_tegra.so
09-06 16:57:45.093: I/DEBUG(122):     #03  pc 00011f98  /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_tegra.so (glDrawArrays+156)
09-06 16:57:45.093: I/DEBUG(122):     #04  pc 00016497  /system/lib/libhwui.so
09-06 16:57:45.093: I/DEBUG(122):     #05  pc 00016549  /system/lib/libhwui.so
09-06 16:57:45.093: I/DEBUG(122):     #06  pc 000107bb  /system/lib/libhwui.so
09-06 16:57:45.093: I/DEBUG(122):     #07  pc 00010a25  /system/lib/libhwui.so
09-06 16:57:45.093: I/DEBUG(122):     #08  pc 00010a25  /system/lib/libhwui.so
09-06 16:57:45.093: I/DEBUG(122):     #09  pc 00010a25  /system/lib/libhwui.so
09-06 16:57:45.093: I/DEBUG(122):     #10  pc 00010a25  /system/lib/libhwui.so
09-06 16:57:45.093: I/DEBUG(122):     #11  pc 00059c8f  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so
09-06 16:57:45.093: I/DEBUG(122):     #12  pc 0001de30  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmPlatformInvoke+112)
09-06 16:57:45.093: I/DEBUG(122):     #13  pc 0004d083  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmCallJNIMethod(unsigned int const*, JValue*, Method const*, Thread*)+394)
09-06 16:57:45.093: I/DEBUG(122):     #14  pc 00027260  /system/lib/libdvm.so
09-06 16:57:45.093: I/DEBUG(122):     #15  pc 0002bb68  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmInterpret(Thread*, Method const*, JValue*)+180)
09-06 16:57:45.093: I/DEBUG(122):     #16  pc 0005fab7  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmInvokeMethod(Object*, Method const*, ArrayObject*, ArrayObject*, ClassObject*, bool)+374)
09-06 16:57:45.093: I/DEBUG(122):     #17  pc 0006700d  /system/lib/libdvm.so
09-06 16:57:45.093: I/DEBUG(122):     #18  pc 00027260  /system/lib/libdvm.so
09-06 16:57:45.093: I/DEBUG(122):     #19  pc 0002bb68  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmInterpret(Thread*, Method const*, JValue*)+180)
09-06 16:57:45.093: I/DEBUG(122):     #20  pc 0005f7f1  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmCallMethodV(Thread*, Method const*, Object*, bool, JValue*, std::__va_list)+272)
09-06 16:57:45.093: I/DEBUG(122):     #21  pc 00049673  /system/lib/libdvm.so
09-06 16:57:45.093: I/DEBUG(122):     #22  pc 0004698d  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so
09-06 16:57:45.093: I/DEBUG(122):     #23  pc 0004746f  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (android::AndroidRuntime::start(char const*, char const*)+390)
09-06 16:57:45.093: I/DEBUG(122):     #24  pc 00000dcf  /system/bin/app_process
09-06 16:57:45.093: I/DEBUG(122): stack:
09-06 16:57:45.093: I/DEBUG(122):          bee122c8  0000002a  
09-06 16:57:45.093: I/DEBUG(122):          bee122cc  0000000c  
09-06 16:57:45.093: I/DEBUG(122):          bee122d0  67070d30  
09-06 16:57:45.093: I/DEBUG(122):          bee122d4  662b21f8  
09-06 16:57:45.093: I/DEBUG(122):          bee122d8  00000610  
09-06 16:57:45.093: I/DEBUG(122):          bee122dc  00000048  
09-06 16:57:45.093: I/DEBUG(122):          bee122e0  00000000  
09-06 16:57:45.093: I/DEBUG(122):          bee122e4  66227561  /system/lib/libardrv_dynamic.so (NvArdShaderWriteFlags+152)
09-06 16:57:45.093: I/DEBUG(122):          bee122e8  00000000  
09-06 16:57:45.093: I/DEBUG(122):          bee122ec  6630cce8  
09-06 16:57:45.093: I/DEBUG(122):          bee122f0  00000000  
09-06 16:57:45.093: I/DEBUG(122):          bee122f4  00000024  
09-06 16:57:45.093: I/DEBUG(122):          bee122f8  00000009  
09-06 16:57:45.093: I/DEBUG(122):          bee122fc  6622a7fd  /system/lib/libardrv_dynamic.so (NvArdLoadVertexConstants_CPU_PIO+32)
09-06 16:57:45.093: I/DEBUG(122):          bee12300  df0027ad  
09-06 16:57:45.093: I/DEBUG(122):          bee12304  00000000  
09-06 16:57:45.093: I/DEBUG(122):     #00  bee12308  662b8470  
09-06 16:57:45.093: I/DEBUG(122):          bee1230c  6624d1b8  
09-06 16:57:45.093: I/DEBUG(122):          bee12310  6630caf8  
09-06 16:57:45.093: I/DEBUG(122):          bee12314  00000001  
09-06 16:57:45.093: I/DEBUG(122):          bee12318  0000082d  
09-06 16:57:45.093: I/DEBUG(122):          bee1231c  662b21fc  
09-06 16:57:45.093: I/DEBUG(122):          bee12320  d5942160  
09-06 16:57:45.093: I/DEBUG(122):          bee12324  6630ceec  
09-06 16:57:45.093: I/DEBUG(122):          bee12328  6624d1b8  
09-06 16:57:45.093: I/DEBUG(122):          bee1232c  00000010  
09-06 16:57:45.093: I/DEBUG(122):          bee12330  00000008  
09-06 16:57:45.093: I/DEBUG(122):          bee12334  00000008  
09-06 16:57:45.093: I/DEBUG(122):          bee12338  00000001  
09-06 16:57:45.093: I/DEBUG(122):          bee1233c  6630cee4  
09-06 16:57:45.093: I/DEBUG(122):          bee12340  00000003  
09-06 16:57:45.093: I/DEBUG(122):          bee12344  67643fa0  /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_tegra.so
09-06 16:57:45.093: I/DEBUG(122):     #01  bee12348  00000000  
09-06 16:57:45.093: I/DEBUG(122):          bee1234c  00000000  
09-06 16:57:45.093: I/DEBUG(122):          bee12350  00000010  
09-06 16:57:45.093: I/DEBUG(122):          bee12354  00000008  
09-06 16:57:45.093: I/DEBUG(122):          bee12358  00000004  
09-06 16:57:45.093: I/DEBUG(122):          bee1235c  6764aa7c  /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_tegra.so
09-06 16:57:45.093: I/DEBUG(122):          bee12360  662b21f8  
09-06 16:57:45.093: I/DEBUG(122):          bee12364  6630ceec  
09-06 16:57:45.093: I/DEBUG(122):          bee12368  662b1f30  
09-06 16:57:45.093: I/DEBUG(122):          bee1236c  00000000  
09-06 16:57:45.093: I/DEBUG(122):          bee12370  00000010  
09-06 16:57:45.093: I/DEBUG(122):          bee12374  662b1f78  
09-06 16:57:45.093: I/DEBUG(122):          bee12378  67687464  /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_tegra.so
09-06 16:57:45.093: I/DEBUG(122):          bee1237c  00000000  
09-06 16:57:45.093: I/DEBUG(122):          bee12380  6624d1b8  
09-06 16:57:45.093: I/DEBUG(122):          bee12384  6624d1b8  
09-06 16:57:45.093: I/DEBUG(122):          ........  ........
09-06 16:57:45.093: I/DEBUG(122):     #02  bee123a8  00000000  
09-06 16:57:45.093: I/DEBUG(122):          bee123ac  00000000  
09-06 16:57:45.093: I/DEBUG(122):          bee123b0  00000000  
09-06 16:57:45.093: I/DEBUG(122):          bee123b4  00000004  
09-06 16:57:45.093: I/DEBUG(122):          bee123b8  00000010  
09-06 16:57:45.093: I/DEBUG(122):          bee123bc  000003fc  
09-06 16:57:45.093: I/DEBUG(122):          bee123c0  00000000  
09-06 16:57:45.093: I/DEBUG(122):          bee123c4  662b1f30  
09-06 16:57:45.093: I/DEBUG(122):          bee123c8  00000000  
09-06 16:57:45.093: I/DEBUG(122):          bee123cc  00000005  
09-06 16:57:45.093: I/DEBUG(122):          bee123d0  00000006  
09-06 16:57:45.093: I/DEBUG(122):          bee123d4  00000000  
09-06 16:57:45.093: I/DEBUG(122):          bee123d8  00000000  
09-06 16:57:45.093: I/DEBUG(122):          bee123dc  00000000  
09-06 16:57:45.093: I/DEBUG(122):          bee123e0  00000004  
09-06 16:57:45.093: I/DEBUG(122):          bee123e4  6624d1b8  
09-06 16:57:45.093: I/DEBUG(122):          ........  ........
09-06 16:57:45.103: I/DEBUG(122): memory near r0:
09-06 16:57:45.103: I/DEBUG(122):     662b1f58 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  ................
09-06 16:57:45.103: I/DEBUG(122):     662b1f68 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  ................
09-06 16:57:45.103: I/DEBUG(122):     662b1f78 c48300e0 66321000 0000c000 00004000  ......2f.....@..
09-06 16:57:45.103: I/DEBUG(122):     662b1f88 00000048 00000100 00002088 00002040  H........ ..@ ..
09-06 16:57:45.103: I/DEBUG(122):     662b1f98 00002040 00000000 00000000 00000020  @ .......... ...
09-06 16:57:45.103: I/DEBUG(122): memory near r1:
09-06 16:57:45.103: I/DEBUG(122):     00002040 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  ................
09-06 16:57:45.103: I/DEBUG(122):     00002050 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  ................
09-06 16:57:45.103: I/DEBUG(122):     00002060 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  ................
09-06 16:57:45.103: I/DEBUG(122):     00002070 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  ................
09-06 16:57:45.103: I/DEBUG(122):     00002080 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  ................
09-06 16:57:45.103: I/DEBUG(122): memory near r5:
09-06 16:57:45.103: I/DEBUG(122):     66323040 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  ................
09-06 16:57:45.103: I/DEBUG(122):     66323050 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  ................
09-06 16:57:45.103: I/DEBUG(122):     66323060 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  ................
09-06 16:57:45.103: I/DEBUG(122):     66323070 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  ................
09-06 16:57:45.103: I/DEBUG(122):     66323080 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  ................
09-06 16:57:45.103: I/DEBUG(122): memory near r9:
09-06 16:57:45.103: I/DEBUG(122):     00002040 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  ................
09-06 16:57:45.103: I/DEBUG(122):     00002050 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  ................
09-06 16:57:45.103: I/DEBUG(122):     00002060 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  ................
09-06 16:57:45.103: I/DEBUG(122):     00002070 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  ................
09-06 16:57:45.103: I/DEBUG(122):     00002080 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  ................
09-06 16:57:45.103: I/DEBUG(122): memory near sl:
09-06 16:57:45.103: I/DEBUG(122):     6630cec4 00000002 00000003 00000000 00000001  ................
09-06 16:57:45.103: I/DEBUG(122):     6630ced4 00000000 00000001 00fe0002 00dc0001  ................
09-06 16:57:45.103: I/DEBUG(122):     6630cee4 00000000 00008b52 00000101 00008b50  ....R.......P...
09-06 16:57:45.103: I/DEBUG(122):     6630cef4 0000ffff 00008b52 00000313 662ba630  ....R.......0.+f
09-06 16:57:45.103: I/DEBUG(122):     6630cf04 6630c410 6630d0d8 00000002 00000002  ..0f..0f........
09-06 16:57:45.103: I/DEBUG(122): memory near sp:
09-06 16:57:45.103: I/DEBUG(122):     bee122e8 00000000 6630cce8 00000000 00000024  ......0f....$...
09-06 16:57:45.103: I/DEBUG(122):     bee122f8 00000009 6622a7fd df0027ad 00000000  ......"f.'......
09-06 16:57:45.103: I/DEBUG(122):     bee12308 662b8470 6624d1b8 6630caf8 00000001  p.+f..$f..0f....
09-06 16:57:45.103: I/DEBUG(122):     bee12318 0000082d 662b21fc d5942160 6630ceec  -....!+f`!....0f
09-06 16:57:45.103: I/DEBUG(122):     bee12328 6624d1b8 00000010 00000008 00000008  ..$f............
09-06 16:57:45.103: I/DEBUG(122): code around pc:
09-06 16:57:45.103: I/DEBUG(122):     67643cf4 eaffffa3 e3540008 13a03000 02033001  ......T..0...0..
09-06 16:57:45.103: I/DEBUG(122):     67643d04 e3530000 01a0800b 0a000007 e1a0300b  ..S..........0..
09-06 16:57:45.103: I/DEBUG(122):     67643d14 e8960003 e2533001 e0866007 e8850003  .....0S..`......
09-06 16:57:45.103: I/DEBUG(122):     67643d24 e2855008 1afffff9 eaffff95 e1a00005  .P..............
09-06 16:57:45.103: I/DEBUG(122):     67643d34 e1a01006 e1a02004 e0855004 ebff2932  ..... ...P..2)..
09-06 16:57:45.103: I/DEBUG(122): code around lr:
09-06 16:57:45.103: I/DEBUG(122):     67643f80 e59de06c e59d002c e59d3068 e58dc004  l...,...h0......
09-06 16:57:45.103: I/DEBUG(122):     67643f90 e58d6008 e58d700c e58de010 ebfffedd  .`...p..........
09-06 16:57:45.103: I/DEBUG(122):     67643fa0 e59d2024 e3520002 e1a01000 0a000050  $ ....R.....P...
09-06 16:57:45.103: I/DEBUG(122):     67643fb0 e2817003 e3c76003 e59d301c e06a1004  .p...`...0....j.
09-06 16:57:45.103: I/DEBUG(122):     67643fc0 e2844008 e19370d1 e3570000 aaffff9c  .@...p....W.....
09-06 16:57:45.263: I/BootReceiver(358): Copying /data/tombstones/tombstone_07 to DropBox (SYSTEM_TOMBSTONE)
09-06 16:57:45.283: I/WindowState(358): WIN DEATH: Window{4181ebd0 com.example.myapp.video/com.example.myapp.video.MainActivity paused=false}
09-06 16:57:45.283: I/ActivityManager(358): Process com.example.myapp.video (pid 14294) has died.
09-06 16:57:45.283: W/ActivityManager(358): Force removing ActivityRecord{415c9a88 com.example.myapp.video/.MainActivity}: app died, no saved state
09-06 16:57:45.333: D/Zygote(124): Process 14294 terminated by signal (11)
```

Comment: Please don't repost questions, even if you delete the old ones.

Comment: I thought I fixed the problem but didnt.  How am I supposed to reask the question?

Comment: If you legitimately deleted a question because you thought you answered it, then it's ok. Next time don't be so hasty. Some people like to spam their question's this way, which is rude.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That sort of crash indicates either a bug in your JNI code (if you have any) or a bug in the firmware. A `SIGSEGV` should be impossible from normal SDK work, even if there are bugs in your code.

If this is on a Nexus device with stock firmware, or if this is on the emulator, or if this reproducible on multiple devices with stock firmware, post an issue to http://b.android.com. Include everything you posted here, including that `SIGSEGV` dump.

If this is on a device with a ROM mod, contact the ROM maintainers first.

Comment: This is run on a stock Nexus 7 with JellyBean.  Also, reproducible on many devices and no JNI code.  Looks like a bug to me. I will file a bug report. Thanks!

Comment: Looks like removing "android:indeterminateOnly="false"" causes it to not crash.  However, that makes my progress bar useless.  Is there another way to create a non-indeterminate progress bar?

Comment: @Nick: A `ProgressBar` is determinate by default, particularly once you start calling `setProgress()`.

Comment: Oddly I am also seeing the issue, I too removed the indeterminantOnly="true", this got rid of the Reinit messages, but left the crash.  And it is on a Nexus 7 with Jelly Bean, but also on a Galaxy Nexus with Jelly Bean.  I do have dueling progress bars, but no idea if that is what the issue is.

Comment: After more digging my crash had to do with a combination of the WebView, shouldIntercept..., SD card access (cache) and video acceleration.  Disabling optimization fixed the problem, or at least makes it so rare I can live with it.  There is a discussion here: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=21266

Comment: Which "optimization" did you disable to get rid of this problem? What kind of link did you find between WebView, SD Card cache and other things? Your answers could help, as I'm facing the same problem now. Thanks